# Mensaje de error en c++

Tags: c++, excepciones, try-catch

Estos son los metodos de mi programa, cuando divido entre 0 se imprime el mensaje de error y despues si imprimen una serie de numeros aleatorios (entiendo el el cout del main no se ejecuta correctamente) Cual es la mejor forma de comprobar que no se divida entre 0?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int dividir(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        cout << "ERROR";           
    }
    else {
        return a / b;
    }
} 

int main(){
    int x=3; int y=0;
    cout<<dividir(x,y);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Como dice @Fran Islas tu funcion no retorna ningun valor en caso de intento de division por cero. Lo adecuado en c++ en la mayoria de los casos es provocar una [`exception`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error).

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdexcept>

    int dividir(int a, int b) {
       if (b == 0) {
          throw std::domain_error( "ERROR: intento de division por cero!");           
       }
       else {
           return a / b;
       }
    } 

    int main(){
       int x=3; int y=0;
       std::cout<<dividir(x,y);
    }
```

En este ejemplo eso es lo adecuado. Para mas control debes decidir que hacer en caso de error y programarlo con un bloque try / catch. Por ejemplo:

```
    int main(){
       int x=3; int y=0;
       try {

       std::cout << dividir(x,y);

       } catch (std::exception& e) {
           std::cout<< e.what();
       } catch (...) {
           std::cout<<"Un error desconocido ha ocurrido!";
       }
    }
```

Comment: Toda la razon @qPCR4vir! Hace años que no toco c++. Me limite a darle una solución rápida y sencilla. Ya que estamos, estaría bueno agregar mas validaciones como por ej: A == 0; A < B. Mostrando un mensaje distinto para cada situación. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Tu función "dividir" no esta retornando valores en todos sus flujos. Te recomiendo imprimir el resultado directamente en la función. Quedando algo así:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 void dividir(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        cout << "ERROR";           
    }
    else {
        cout << (a/b);
    }
} 

int main(){
    int x=3; int y=0;
    dividir(x,y);
}
```

Saludos!